# For Loops with Multiple Variables - Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, for-loop

I am attempting to code a particular algorithm, called the Verlet Algorithm, which basically updates the values of certain variables, called x,v and E, each time the algorithm runs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# set constants
k = 1
m = 1

#Set the number of iterations to be used in the for loop
no_of_iterations=1001



# make arrays to define the data
t = np.zeros(no_of_iterations)
x = np.zeros(no_of_iterations)
v = np.zeros(no_of_iterations)
E = np.zeros(no_of_iterations)

# set initial conditions
t[0] = 0
x[0] = 0
v[0] = 1
E[0] = 0


# make arrays to store data
x1=[]
v1=[]
E1=[]




'''N = 4 Loops'''
#loop for dt = 0.1,N = 4,j=1
for N in range(1,5,1):
    for i in range(1,no_of_iterations):
            j = 1
            x[0]= np.sin((np.pi*j*k)/(N+1))
            t_max = 100.0
            dt = t_max/no_of_iterations  #time step
            t[i] = dt * i
            v[i] = v[i-1] - ((dt *k/m*(x[N]-x[N-1]))/2)
            x[i] = x[i-1] + dt * v[i]
            E[i] = ((((v[i])**2)/2) + (x[N]-x[N-1]))
            x1.append(x[i])
            v1.append(v[i])
            E1.append(E[i])
```

Essentially what this is doing is appending the updated values of x,v and E to empty lists, while given certain initial conditions.

Now my problem comes from the fact that my variables that I'm looping over have many different values:

*N = 4,16,128* : *dt = 0.1,0.01* : *j = 1,N/2*

and I am supposed to plot each array I create, and example of which is shown below:

Plot for N = 4, dt = 0.1, j = 1

[image]

( With my N = 4 loop)

One problem is that I am storing ALL the values of N=1,2,3,4 into one list, called x1, while I actually want to have 4 separate lists, one for each value of N that I iterate over, ie.  x1_N1, x2_N2, x3_N3, x4_N4.

But even if I do that things will get pretty messy pretty quickly. For example, with N=128, I should have 4 graphs( (dt = 0.1 and  j = 1) , (dt = 0.01 and  j = 1) , (dt = 0.01 and  j = N/2) , (dt = 0.01 and  j = N/2) ) each with 128 lists. Thus I would have to create 8 for loops just for N = 4!

So, is there a way to create a new list inside this for loop and append it, rather than having to define an empty list outside of it?

Edit:  Thank you guys for commenting!

I'm using the Verlet algorithm to solve the equation of motion of many coupled oscillators:

[image: Equation of motion in the form of a Hamiltonian]

H is the variable E in my code. N is the number of oscillators. Dv/Dx = x_n - x_N-1 is the force.

The actual algorithm is done by the following:

[image: Verlet Algoithm Implementation]

where τ is dt in my code.

Now what I'm actually doing with this code is:

[image: What I'm doing with this code]

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what j is! I think it's just a variable used to change the initial condition of the position variable x?

Once again thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you explain what does each variable mean? `N` is the number of series to plot, `dt` is the time increment, but what is `j`?

Comment: I also think you have some algorithm issue when calculating `v[i]` as you are using `x[N]` to calculate it.

Comment: Please do a section purely on the physics of the problem. What is the energy function, the force, the acceleration, why is it conservative. It seems that you want to implement the Leapfrog Verlet method, however it appears top be done wrong. With the wrong initialization you get the order 1 symplectic Euler method. What exactly are the different runs for, what are you comparing?

Comment: According to the Verlet algorithm implementation you posted v(t) and x(t) both depend on their own values, so those have to be obtained from the previous iteration for sure, but they also depend on each other (v(t) depends on u that depends on x(t) and x(t) directly depends on v(t)) so one of them have to be obtained from the previous iteration. I will post a solution that calculates u from the previous iteration and then resolves the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I left the print statements commented but they are not useful in the provided example as there are many iterations and combinations and the terminal will overflow. If you modify the list to have just one posible combination and reduce the number of iterations a bit, uncommenting them will show each step. Do not forget to also uncomment `np.set_printoptions()` then.

I also left matplotlib's legends commented as 129 legends are also too many to display correctly. I'm plotting both all the `x`s with `E` and all the `v`s with `E`.

`j=0` is the special case where all initial conditions are 0 except for `x_(N/2) = 1`. The rest of `j` will act as the second initial condition case you wrote.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)


combinations = []
for no_iterations in [1000]:
    for t_end in [10, 100]:
        for N in [4, 16, 128]:
            for j in [0, 1, N//2]:
                combinations.append({
                    "no_iterations": no_iterations,
                    "t_end": t_end,
                    "N": N,
                    "j": j,
                })


for vars_dict in combinations:
    ''' Extract the vars from the dict '''
    no_iterations = vars_dict["no_iterations"]
    t_end = vars_dict["t_end"]
    dt = t_end / no_iterations
    N = vars_dict["N"]
    j = vars_dict["j"]
    ''' Print the variables '''
    print(" N = {:3} | dt = {:.2f} | j = {:2}".format(N, dt, j))
    #print("-"*80)
    ''' Create the arrays for the different values '''
    v = np.zeros( (no_iterations + 1, N) )
    x = np.zeros( (no_iterations + 1, N) )
    E = np.zeros(no_iterations + 1)
    ''' Initial conditions (t=0) '''
    if j == 0:
        x[0][N//2 - 1] = 1
    else:
        for k in range(1, N+1):
            x[0][k-1] = np.sin(np.pi*j*k/(N+1))
    E[0] = 0.5 * (sum(map(lambda x: x**2, v[0])) + sum(map(lambda x, y: x - y, x[0][1:], x[0][:-1])))
    #print("t={:4} x={} v={} E={:+.4f}".format(0, x[0], v[0], E[0]))
    ''' Loop (t=1..no_iterations) '''
    for t in range(1, no_iterations+1):
        for k in range(1, N+1):
            if k == 1:
                u = x[t-1][0] - x[t-1][1]
            elif k == N:
                u = x[t-1][N-1] - x[t-1][N-2]
            else:
                u = 2* x[t-1][k-1] - x[t-1][k-2] - x[t-1][k]
            v[t][k-1] = v[t-1][k-1] - dt * u/2
            x[t][k-1] = x[t-1][k-1] + dt * v[t][k-1]
        E[t] = 0.5 * (sum(map(lambda x: x**2, v[t])) + sum(map(lambda x, y: x - y, x[t][1:], x[t][:-1])))
        #print("t={:4} x={} v={} E={:+.4f}".format(t, x[t], v[t], E[t]))
    ''' The x axis for plotting '''
    t = np.linspace(0, t_end, no_iterations+1)
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    for k in range(1, N+1):
        ax1.plot(t, x[:,k-1], label="x_{}".format(k))
        ax2.plot(t, v[:,k-1], label="v_{}".format(k))
        pass
    ax1.plot(t, E, label="Energy")
    ax2.plot(t, E, label="Energy")
    # ax1.legend()
    # ax2.legend()
    plt.show()
    print("-"*80)
    print()
```

First im creating a `list` called `combinations` that has a `dict`s with all the possible variable combinations extracted from the 4 lists in the four first `for` loops. I was tempted to use constants at the start of the script to show that they can be edited by the user but the last `list` depends on `N` and that can only be known inside the third loop so I left all of them in the loops.

Then the next loop is iterating over all combinations and extracting the variables from the `dict` for a cleaner syntax. I'm also calculating `dt`.

I'm creating two matrixes where the first index represents the time instant and the second one the subindex in case of `x_n` and `v_n` and a vector for `E`. The first instant of this matrixes/vector are initiated as you described, using the special case of `j == 0` for the special case you mentioned.

A loop is then entered to iterate over all the remaining instants and all the `x_n(t)`, `v_n(t)` are calculated first so that we can calculate `E(t)`. This is the part that may be wrong as I did the asumption that `u` is calculated from the previous instant. If you know how to solve this kind of problems by hand you may be able to correct this part in case that assumption is wrong.

We are then creating the `t` vector for the x axis at the end (as we were using the variable `t` inside the previous loop for another thing) with `np.linspace(start, end, number)` which gives a vector with `number` elements fron `start` to `end` including both.

We use a 2 rows plot to print `x_n` and `E` in the top part and `v_n` and `E` again in the bottom part.

Comment: Edited to include the new info given in the OP

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! There's a lot of really cool code in there! Spent a while today deciphering it and I have learned so much! I genuinely appreciate all your help.

Comment: You could have asked for some explanation and I could have helped you there. Will edit to include it.